# How can I show that this set is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

How can I show that this set is bounded?

> Montrez que l'ensemble
> $$A = \left\{\frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}; (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2, (x,y)\ne (0,0)\right\}$$
> est borné.

[(Source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViXRT.png)

this is my try answer

FIRST: I tried to put an R that belongs to A so R=sin(xy)/x²+y²

SECOND: I turnd the equality into inequality and I put the absolute value like that: |R|<=|sin(xy)|/x²+y² and after that I stucked because i didn't find the way how to solve this inequality and my target is to find borders for sin(xy)/x²+y²,Once I find them i can say that's bounded.

Comment: Is it "show that the set is bounded"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: yes exactly this is the question in english.........                                                                              I tried to put an R that it's absolute value is lower or equal to the absolute value of sin(xy)/x²+y² but then  i couldnt solve the inequality

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: Also, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and type your question, don't post images.

Comment: Finally, translate your questions to english, it's the official language of this site.

Comment: okey,I put my try answer and I changed the title,next time I wont post picture I'll type.

Comment: You can see my try answer and help me solve the question

Comment: The idea is that you should put your attempts in the question (Please read the guidelines shown to you prior to asking the question) Otherwise, to other users, it looks like that someone has already answered the question.

Comment: okey,done......

Comment: Hint: what happens when $(x,y)$ is far from the origin?

Comment: @ArcticChar actually I don't know ! that what i'm searching about from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
If you know that

1. $|\sin(a)| \leq |a|$ for all $a \in \R$.
2. $2|xy| \leq x^2 + y^2$ for all $x,y\in\R$ because $(|x|-|y|)^2 \geq 0$

$$
\frac{|\sin(xy)|}{x^2 + y^2}
\leq
\frac{|xy|}{x^2 + y^2}
\leq
\frac{1}{2}
$$
for all $(x,y) \in \R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: great ! and then finally i'll find  -0,5<|sin(xy)|/x²+y²<0,5....which means that A has the same VALUE of bound in both sides (upper bound and lower bound),isn't it ?

Comment: @SorayaForward Yes, except that you have to remove $|\cdot|$ around $\sin(xy)$. But I don't know whether you understand why you can remove the equality from $\leq$.

Comment: oh yes! I'm doing too much mistakes while writing..Actually I forgot to remove the absolute value However I do not know why I can remove the equality from <= I didnt pay attention when I wrote it without the =

Comment: @SorayaForward Condition 1 can be slightly changed: whenever $|a| > 0$, we have $\sin(a) < |a|$ and this fact can be proved in several ways. I recommend you to visit http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers

Comment: Thank u so much for ur help